# How to execute Ribbon command to change font size

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some Excel tables that I copy to Powerpoint with `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")` method to keep source formatting. However Powerpoint tends to change font size for it's own reason and I would like to fix it. First obvious idea is to iterate over all cells of the table and set font size, but it's terribly slow, thus useless. It's still better to change it manually.

I decided it would be the best to call Ribbon method that changes font size. In other words imitate user clicking font change combo box. However I failed to find how to do it. I checked `Application.CommandBars` object, but it doesn't let me work with Ribbon. It even has `FontSize` control, but I didn't manage to use it successfully. For me it looks like legacy class from 'pre-Ribbon' times.

I also hoped to find right argument for `ExecuteMso` method, but there are only `FontSizeDecrease`, `FontSizeDecrease`, and `FontDialog`.

I believe there's a way to interact with Ribbon through VBA, but I didn't manage to find clear enough reference.

To sum up, my question is **how to simulate user changing font size on Ribbon in Powerpoint**.

Comment: What kind of Ribbon Control are you looking for? For example ExecuteMso("FontSize16") ?? Not sure why it's so important to simulate the ribbon for you. Instead of iterating over the cells, can VBA set the font on the entire table? Which part of the iteration is slow?

Comment: Does `ExecuteMso("FontSize16")` work for you? I've just tried it, but I get `Invalid procedure call or argument`. If it worked, it would be perfect solution. As for iteration, I tried two `For Each` loops (for rows and cells), but it takes around 0.5 second for each cell, so it's unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was just trying to understand the question and "FontSize16" was a hypothetical answer. Thanks for clarifying, I can't think of a better solution than interop.

Comment: I worked it around successfully. All cells in my table, except for headers, have the same font size, even if it was changed by Powerpoint. Therefore I'm able to check one cell, and use `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FontSizeIncrease")` for whole table necessary number of times (usually 1). Not perfect, but works for uniform tables.